# What does h = httplib2.Http('.cache') mean?

Tags: python, httplib2

What does line 2 (`h = httplib2.Http('.cache')`) mean here?

```
>>> import httplib2
>>> h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
```

Comment: Try to visit: https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`httplib2.HTTP()` documentation string](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/blob/master/python3/httplib2/__init__.py#L870-L872):

> If 'cache' is a string then it is used as a directory name for a disk cache. Otherwise it must be an object that supports the same interface as FileCache.

The line creates an instance of the `HTTP()` class, and sets the `cache` parameter to `.cache`, meaning that a `.cache` directory in the current working directory is used for cached data.

From the [*Usage* section](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/#usage) of the project documentation you can see that the cache is used to cache responses according to HTTP caching rules; the cache will honour cache headers set on the response unless you override those headers with corresponding request headers.